# What is a good strategy for adding additional information in a GET query over REST?

Tags: rest

Given that we provide a restful api that serves book entities listening at

```
/books
```

And a client can get a book at the usual

```
GET /books/{id}
```

Suppose that we want to begin offering discounts on books to only our most vigilant buyers.  These buyers would be given a discount code, and that code will reduce the price of the book.

Thus, a generic response may be

```
 GET /books/4
 {"id":4, "price":"24.95"}
```

Where a response to a query with a discount code may be

```
 GET /books/4
 {"id":4, "price":"24.95", "yourPrice":"19.95"}
```

The back-end processing we can get figured out, but **what is the best practice for a client submitting a discount code over a restful api?**

Certain books will be eligible for discounts while others will not.  Discounts will not be broad (20% off everything), but instead will map to a specific price for that particular code (or client/code combo).

We've considered:

- kludging the url

  GET /codes/{someCode}/books/{id}
- Adding the code in a header value
- Using a query string

  GET /books?code=myCode
- anything else?

**EDIT**: Our goal is not to implement single-use codes.  Instead, these discount codes could be used some fixed number of times for some fixed set of books.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like using query variables. I just looked at the *RESTful Web Services* book, my main reference in this area, and they say:

> Use query variables only to suggest
>   arguments being plugged into an
>   algorithm... If two URIs differ only
>   in their query variables, it implies
>   they're the different sets of inputs
>   into the same underlying algorithm.

It seems to me your discount codes are inputs to a discounting algorithm.

Charles

Comment: "Use query variables only to suggest arguments being plugged into an algorithm..." That certainly is the case here.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to be submitting anything that's not idempotent, I would suggest using POST instead of GET.  You wouldn't want a client to be able to use their code more than once.

Comment: Actually code expiration isn't an issue here.  I'll update the question to reflect this.  Your remark about idempotent is still relevant regardless.

Answer (score 1):

Anything you add in the URL or header values are open to be intercepted, and possibly allowing other users to 'fake' their discount ID. 1 approach would be to introduce a new POST call, that will allow the ID to be encrypted with simple HTTPS. The POSTed data could be as simple as the discountID or customerID.

Added - Sorry Michael, you already said that :)

Comment: Using POST to perform an action that is GETting a list of books feels wrong.  Good point about keeping the code secure, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can register the code in a table so when the user retrieves that book automatically returns that book with the proper discount, for example:

The user can add some code

```
POST /register/{code}
```

This will add an entry to a table {user} - {code} so when the user retrieves by

```
GET /books/{id}
```

will use that entry to apply the discount. I'm guessing that you already have some relation between {code}-{book} so wont get into that.